# Convert JPG to HTML

Tags: html, css, jpeg, psd

I am quite new to web development so I wanted to ask people here if there exists any software which can convert JPG/PSD to its respective HTML/CSS equivalent?

I am not looking to embed the image in the HTML but want HTML/CSS source which will be equivalent of that JPG from which it is converted.

Thanks,

Saarthak

Comment: Nope, you'd have to do it by hand.

Comment: Related: [Best Way to Convert PSD to CSS/HTML File?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/45903)

Comment: It would be very popular if it existed :)

Comment: @alex: it does, but not sure how popular it is :) - (see answer below)

Comment: @Ryan I don't know if generating images with `td` cells is quite what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @alex: then the question should be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

even I am quite new to designing because m a developer but ADOBE fireworks is the tool thet lets you convert jpg/jpeg in respective html/css Although it will not convert the whole for you but it'll convert atleast 60% of the layout to html/css.

more tutorials can be found [Here](http://tv.adobe.com/product/fireworks/)

excuse me if i was wrong anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had stumbled upon this a long time ago.

Try [img2html](http://pgl.yoyo.org/img2html/). It seems to do what you want. [text-image.com](http://www.text-image.com/convert/) is another one, but the sample 'hand-holding-beer' file looks better when converted using img2html :)

Comment: Please note that I wrote that (img2html) in 2003! It's not exactly the most polished script in the world.